# How can I stop Finder from prompting me every time I delete something from a network drive?

Tags: finder, macos

Every time I delete a file or folder from a shared drive Finder prompts me asking if I'm sure I'd like to delete it. How can I stop this prompt from appearing?[image]

Comment: This won't answer your question, but I'd expect you don't want to do what you're suggesting. Say you right click (or control + click) on something to rename it but you accidentally hit the delete button. They'd be NO way to undo it (this message occurs because network drives have no "trash" like wired drives do).

Comment: @NoahL I'm using a Synology NAS which does have a trash.